# How to change the size of an input box in ms access 2003

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, ms-access-2003, inputbox

the msg box was prompted with code :

StrInput = InputBox(Prompt:=strMsg, Title:="Location of Files", XPos:=2000, YPos:=2000)

im not sure how to change the size of the box. i want to because my strMsg is quite logn and doesnt look nice in a small box.

Comment: Surely you want a file open/folder open dialog? InputBox() is a very primitive way to collect information interactively and I would never use it for something like this. You might try Googling "Access BrowseFolder".

Comment: o nah i wasnt trying to get a file i just had a lot of instructions that came with the message box . some theres quite a bit in the 'strmsg' and it didnt look that good all crowded in the tiny box

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way I'm aware of to change the size of the inputbox.  You have a couple of choices:

1) Force line breaks with vbCRLF like this:
`message = "This line will end here: " & vbcrlf & "This appears on a new line"

2) Create your own form to act an input box.  Depending on your VBA ability you can make a form with a textbox, label, OK button, and cancel button.  Have that form use the string in the form opening arguments (OpenArgs) as the prompt text.  That will give you a generic, customizable inputbox.

Comment: I've tried the first and it didn't work. maybe I'll give the secodn a try but thats mroe difficult than i wouldve hoped =(  . maybe changing the size of an input box is nto possible

Comment: Unfortunately, even if it is possible it would probably require WinAPI calls and add the sort of complexity where you'd be better served by making your own inputbox anyway.

Comment: +1 for suggestion #2, which is really the only possible way to do this without overcomplicating things.